# Malchus Yishmael and the connection with clay

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, messianic-redemption, golus-exile, daniel-book-of

I was stuyding the Midrash Rabbah [(Bereishis Rabbah 2:4)](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereshit_Rabbah.2.4?lang=bi) on the four galuyos and why Malchus Yishmael isn't included.

This got me to sefer [Daniel 2:31-33](https://www.sefaria.org/Daniel.2.31-33?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). There, we read about a great statue, with a high gloss, iron feet, iron legs and clay feet.

> Thou, O king, didst see, and behold a great image. This image, which
> was mighty, and whose brightness was surpassing stood before thee; and
> its form was terrible.  This image’s head was of fine gold, its breast
> and its arms of silver, its belly and its thighs of brass,  its legs
> of iron, its feet partly of iron and partly of clay.

The word the Torah uses for "clay" is חֲסַֽף.

[Rabbi Yoel Schwartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoel_Schwartz) wrote in his sefer "Davar Be'ito" that the "legs of iron" refer to Malchus Edom, and "feet of clay" refer to Malchus Yishmael (דבר בעתו - אבלות החורבן, sv. גלות ישמעאל p. 32). See also Shivlei Pinchas, 5779, Parashas Vayishlach:

> This is consistent with Nevuchadnetzar’s dream depicted in Daniel (2, 34).  One of the creature’s legs was made of iron, representing Edom; and one of its legs was made of clay, representing Yishmael.

Refer also to sefer "Keitz HaYamin" by Rabbi Yisrael Moshe Sorotzkin (Vol. 1, p. 113 & 137).

I tried to search why especially clay is connected to Malchus Yishmael but could not find anything special. Does anyone know why Malchus Yishmael can be connected with "clay"? Are there any explanations for this?

The Midrash Tanchuma says iron is hard, so will the kingdom will be hard. Clay is breakable, so will the kingdom be easiliy breakable. But that does not fit in well with Yishmael.

Comment: And why would Malchus Edom have anything to do with iron?

Comment: Why doesn't that fit as a description of yishmael?

Comment: The Midrash refers to Malchus Edom, not to Yishmael. Second: the Zohar says in Shemos 17a that the Galus Yishmael will be the toughest one. Also, there was a need that Rabbi Schwartz saw the need to mention it seperately.

Comment: "_Rabbi Yoel Schwartz wrote in his sefer 'Davar Be'ito' that the 'legs of iron' refer to Malchus Edom, and 'feet of clay' refer to Malchus Yishmael (דבר בעתו - אבלות החורבן, sv. גלות ישמעאל p. 32)._" Do you mean [this](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47119&pgnum=27)? If so, he is saying so as the opinion of R. Saadia Gaon. He also says that the Maharal differs, and says that Yishmael is included in Malchus Paras.

Comment: @TamirEvan thank you. I am familiair with the opinion of the Maharal in Ner Mitzvah, but why is Yishmael connected to clay?